# Validar un Combobox dinamico con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, mysqli

Actualmente tengo un combo dinámico donde al seleccionar un Estado te arroja el debido Municipio al que pertenece ese Estado.

Lo que quiero es validar desde el lado del Servidor que efectivamente pertenezca a ese estado el municipio seleccionado, ya que vista cliente es muy fácil modificar el combo por cualquier otro input.

Ahora bien si se que al Seleccionar estado de México los Municipios son: Texcoco, Chalco, La Paz por mencionar algunos, como haría esta validación:

Actualmente tengo esto así:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $municipio = $_POST['municipio'];

    if (!preg_match("/^México$|^Puebla$/", $estado)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Estado Incorrecto";
    } else {
        echo "<font color='#2ecc71'>Estado Correcto";
    }

    $buscar = array ( "México" => "Chimalhuacán","Chicoloapan",
             "Puebla" => "Chila","Amozóc", );

    if($buscar[$estado] == $municipio){
        echo "<font color='#2ecc71'>Muy bien, el Municipio si pertenece al Estado Seleccionado";
    } else {
        echo "<font color='red'>Incorrecto, el Municipio no corresponde al Estado Seleccionado";
    }       
}

<form class = "form-horizontal" method = "POST" action ="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" autocomplete ="off">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado" value="<?php if(isset($estado)) echo $estado ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">  
        <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Municipio</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="municipio" name="municipio" value="<?php if(isset($municipio)) echo $municipio ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name = "submit" class="btn"Actualizar</button>
</form>
```

Pero aun no consigo mi objetivo.
Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme a resolver este inconveniente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que hacer los estados arrays.  De ese mode puedes chequear si el municipio pertenece al estado con `in_array`.  Algo asi:

```
$buscar = array ( "México" => array("Chimalhuacán","Chicoloapan"),
         "Puebla" => array("Chila","Amozóc") );

if(in_array($municipio, $buscar[$estado]))
{
   echo "<font color='#2ecc71'>Muy bien, el Municipio si pertenece al Estado Seleccionado";
} else {
   echo "<font color='red'>Incorrecto, el Municipio no corresponde al Estado Seleccionado";
}
```

Comment: quedo muy bien gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo plantearia el array de buscar de un modo distinto. Pondria como clave el municipio, y como valor el estado. Esto es:

```
$buscar = array(
    "Cimalhuacan" => "Mexico",
    "Chicoloapan" => "Mexico",
    "Chila" => "Puebla",
    "Amozoc" => "Puebla
);
```

de esta manera, ya que conoces el estado y el municipio, puedes preguntar por:

```
if ($buscar[$municipio] == $estado) {
   echo "<font color='#2ecc71'>Muy bien, el Municipio si pertenece al Estado Seleccionado";
} else {
    echo "<font color='red'>Incorrecto, el Municipio no corresponde al Estado Seleccionado";
}
```

Comment: lo intentaré gracias